# Doing a float division without installing additional gems?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, division

Let's say I have these two floats:

```
a = 50.0
b = 1048576.0
c = a/b
```

By printing `c`, I get this:

```
4.76837158203125e-005
```

Doing the division with `calc.exe` gives me the result 0.0000476837158203125 . Is there any way of achieving the same thing with Ruby without installing any additional gem?

Comment: The division works fine. It's how the number is represented that's the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = 50.0
b = 1048576.0
c = a/b
#=> 4.76837158203125e-005
sprintf("%.20f", c)
#> "0.00004768371582031250"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can format a float using [string formatting](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000770) in Ruby like so:

```
irb> "%.019f" % c
=> "0.0000476837158203125"
```

Comment: won't be enough `"%.19f" % c`? why do you use additional zero?

Comment: yes, you are right, I just used the zero padding from habit of printing integers but it is not necessary.